# Why do These Black Boxes Appear in Windows 7, and How Can I Prevent Them?

Tags: windows-7, graphics

Seemingly randomly, black boxes begin to appear on many of the programs I have open. Here's what they look like:

**Photoshop:**
[image: Photoshop]

**foobar2000:**
[image: foobar2000]

---

When I restart my computer, the boxes go away. I have yet to find the source of these boxes. How do I prevent these things from appearing?

Comment: What graphic card do you have and which driver?

Comment: Radeon HD 6870. Current driver version: 8.850.0.0

Comment: Definitely looks like graphics artifacting. I would ensure your drivers are up to date and that your card is working properly (e.g. not overheating).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your graphics card isn't overheating. You can use [speccy](http://www.piriform.com/speccy) to check the temperature. Make sure all the fans are spinning in your computer and that none of them are clogged with dust. A steady increase in the number of black boxes after startup might be explained by a steady increase in heat that isn't being blown away.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a problem with your graphics card.
Since they don't appear immediately, I would assume a problem with the driver.

Try removing and reinstalling the drivers with the latest version from [AMD](http://support.amd.com/us/Pages/AMDSupportHub.aspx).